# password encryption in Yii to sha512

Tags: php, encryption, yii

I'm trying ot make a Sha512 encryption for the passwords in Yii, but it isn;t working

i beleive the code is this `$model->PassWord=crypt($model->PassWord,'salt');`

But i am getting this as an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function CRYPT_SHA512() in protected/controllers/UsersController.php on line 73`

Any ideas?

Full code:

```
    public function actionCreate()
   {
       $model=new Users;

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['Users']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
    $model->PassWord=crypt_SHA512($model->PassWord,'salt');
    if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->users_id));
}

$this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
   }
```

***edit***

This `$model->PassWord=crypt($model->PassWord,'$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt');` makes the password encrypted, Great!

Now when trying to login i get this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /web/users/m2052626/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/protected/components/UserIdentity.php on line 25`

This is my code originally for the login

```
public function authenticate()
    {
            $user=Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    //else if($record->PassWord!==md5($this->password))

    else if($user->PassWord!==($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->users_id;
       // $this->setState('title', $record->title);
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
```

And i have tried to replace this `else if($user->PassWord!==($this->password))` with this `if (crypt($this->password '$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt') == $user->PassWord) { echo "password matched"; } else { echo "password did not match"; }` which didnt work

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339036/use-of-undefined-constant-crypt-sha512 ?

Comment: 1. You probably need to show the code that the error message refers to. 2. SHA-512 is a hashing function and not an encryption algorithm. A hash cannot be reversed.

Comment: Added code, How would i go about doing this then to sha512?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call

```
$model->PassWord=crypt_SHA512($model->PassWord,'salt');
```

Looks to me like you are trying to call the module name and not the function.  The function is still just crypt(plaintext, salt);  In the salt string you pick the hash function, and include the number of rounds (for SHA encyption) as well as your salt (which should be exactly 16 characters long in this case)   as separated by '$'.  So your call would really look like this:

```
$model->PassWord=crypt($model->PassWord,'$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt');
```

In the code above the salt string starts with a $ (required) followed by 6 (the number of the SHA512 hash), then $round=1212 where the 1212 is the number of rounds you want SHA to run (must be more than 1000), finally a $ and your salt.

here's the manual:
http://php.net/crypt

Comment: Hey there, This is obviously for the user registration, How would i go about getting it bak for users logging in. `else if($user->PassWord!==crypt($this->password,'salt'))` Somehting like this?

Comment: actually that is almost exactly it (minus your extra '=' or maybe your '!' depending on what you are checking).  Basically compare your saved, hashed password (from above) to the result of a new hash of the users login attempt.   Keep in mind that salt has to be the same as the salt you used from the first call.

A good way to do this and to keep the salt unique for each user (which is also valuable) is to include the user name in the 16 character salt.

Comment: forgive me for being stupid! please talk to me like im 5! so it should be `else if($user->PassWord!=crypt($this->password,'$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt'))`

Comment: `if (crypt($this->password '$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt') == $user->PassWord) 
{
 echo "password matched";
} else {
 echo "password did not match";
}`

Hope that's readable.

Comment: will give it a shoot now

Comment: should be after the **edit** in the main question :)

Comment: line 25 is ` else if($user->PassWord!==($this->password)) ` which is the one that i changed with you solution :)

Comment: ah, it looks like my code is missing a comma:
`if (crypt($this->password, '$6$rounds=1212$16charactersaltt') == $user->PassWord)`

Comment: After all this fighting with it it works! Thanks a bunch! Probably just saved my a**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76836/discussion-between-sam-roberts-and-devhours).